# full table scan in mysql

Tags: mysql, optimization, full-table-scan

`select *from REPT_AIR_PRY_HY1 RAP where 
  (RAP.DATE_OF_ISSUE) BETWEEN "2017-10-01" AND DATE_ADD("2017-10-31", INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

the explain plan of this query gives me **337243**
but data s between these dates is only **55209** and there is even index is created on column DATE_OF_ISSUE . So, why it is scanning the whole table?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

- The optimizer thinks (correctly or incorrectly) that a non-trivial percentage of the table would be needed.  How many rows in the table?
- You are using MyISAM; switch to InnoDB.
- For some reason, the 'statistics' are stale.  Do `ANALYZE TABLE`.

To discuss further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: 1. the total records found in the specified table is 408025, but the carnality   of index created for  DATE_OF_ISSUE column is 337243 .   
2.am using InnoDB only.

Comment: All statistics, including that cardinality, are approximations.  That's off by 20% -- I've seen it off by a factor of 2 sometimes.  Newer versions of MySQL tend to be slightly better.

Comment: So there is no solution for this.